# Angular freezing when binding a function

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, data-binding

TL;DR, how can I bind a function like so without having the browser freeze?

```
<ion-chip *ngFor="let m of chatroom.members">
    <ion-label>{{getName(m.uid)}}</ion-label>
</ion-chip>
```

The idea is that I have a chat room and I would like to display the users who are members in it. Here is my Firebase data:

[image: Firebase]

The idea is that only the uids of the users will be stored in an array called `members`. When it comes to retrieving from the database, the following service retrieves a user based on the uid:

***GetUserFromDatabaseService.ts***

```
import { User } from 'src/app/objects/classes/user';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetUserFromDatabaseService {
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { }

  async retrieveUser(uid: string) {
    let user: User = null;
    await this.afs.collection('USERS').doc(uid).ref.get().then(async function (doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
        user = doc.data() as User;//User is my custom class that has the name of the user.
      } else {
        console.log("There is no document!");
      }
      return user;
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log("There was an error getting your document:", error);
    });
    return user;
  }
}
```

In my *chatroom.ts*, this is what I have:

***chatroom.ts***

```
...
currentMemberName: string = '';
...
async getName(uid: string): Promise<string> {
    this.currentMemberName = (await this.getUserFromDataBase.retrieveUser(uid)).name;
    return this.currentMemberName;
}
...
```

In my *chatroom.page.html*, I will loop through the `members` array and I want to retrieve the names of all the users based on their uids. It will look something like:

***chatroom.page.html***

```
...
<ion-chip *ngFor="let m of chatroom.members">
    <ion-label>{{getName(m.uid)}}</ion-label>
</ion-chip>
...
```

**My solution:**

The solution that I have come up with is to create a new array (call it `names`) which basically pre-retrieves the names from the database and store them as `string`s. My *chatroom.page.html* would then look like:

```
...
<ion-chip *ngFor="let n of names">
    <ion-label>{{n}}</ion-label>
</ion-chip>
...
```

I am not too happy with it as I will store twice the data (at least temporarily). Is there a way to make this more efficient?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Your app should be asynchronous, here I am seeing async await which will make it kinda sync. This will defiantly freeze your application till async wait function finishes.

Comment: @Plochie can you please give me a complete solution? I have been playing with async/await for 3 straight days now and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Try using the `async` pipe: `<ion-label>{{getName(m.uid) | async}}</ion-label>`. Moreover, I don't really understand the `retrieveUser` method. Why wait synchronously for a promise, only to return a different promise with the same value ?

Comment: @ethanfar, I have tried the `async` pipe but it didn't work. Also, what would you suggest to do? I am a mere beginner when it comes to promises and observables. Any code snippet will be helpful.

Comment: @M.AlJumaily It's a little hard attaching code in a comment, but basically, just replace `await` with `return` and lost the `return user;` at the end.

Comment: @ethanfar, Thank you for the comment. What should I do in my **chatroom.ts** to use the service? I cannot use what I have and I don't really know what I am returning in the service.

Comment: @M.AlJumaily Well, if you follow my suggestion, you'll be returning a promise. To use it, either chain a callback to it with `.then(...)` or an error handler with `.catch(...)`, or you can use `await` within a try & catch block. I suggest you do some reading about promises in Javascript, it might help you understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to `async` `await`, your program is waiting for the output in synchronous way. This results in freezing application.

Now Javascript is single threaded language, so if you wait for something then your application will freeze. For this we can use `Promise`, with `Promise` we will get callback when there is value available. This is async approach.

**Service**

```js
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetUserFromDatabaseService {
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { }

  retrieveUser(uid: string) {
    return this.afs.collection('USERS').doc(uid).ref.get();
  }
}
```

**chatroom.ts** (call `getNames` function after receiving `chatroom.member`)

```js
memberNames: string[] = [];

getNames() {
    chatroom.members.forEach(member => {
        this.getUserFromDataBase.retrieveUser(member.uid).then(doc => {
            this.memberNames.push((doc.data() as User).name);
        });
    });
}
```

**chatroom.page.html**

```html
<ion-chip *ngFor="let m of memberNames">
    <ion-label>{{m}}</ion-label>
</ion-chip>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate further regarding how you are using an observable in the service.ts? Also, the array `memberNames` is empty, do I need to push the `currentMemberName` inside my `getNames()` function?

Comment: Further to elaborate, what you ware doing earlier is waiting for the response which makes your application sync. Now javascript is single threaded language, so if you wait for something then your application will freeze. For this we can use observables, with observables we will get callback when there is value available. This is async approach.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The observable import is not being used in service.ts and the `retrieveUser` function returns a promise, what is the fix please?

Comment: Okey. So instead of subscribe you need to use `then`. updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! So your approach is similar to mine that we still have to temporarily store the data twice but works better :)